# Is there an efficient way to do "continuous" auto-focus?

Tags: android, camera, focus

I'm working on an android app using the camera, and the only means of focusing the image I've found requires the use of the built-in auto-focus.  Its functionality is great when you're looking to take a picture, but when you're working with video it's a whole other story.

Is there a way to repeatedly adjust the focus without having to completely re-set the current focus?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO).

*edit*

Not that I believe the site will go away anytime soon, but just in case:

```
public static final String FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO
```

> Continuous auto focus mode intended for video recording. The camera continuously tries to focus. This is ideal for shooting video. Applications still can call     `takePicture(Camera.ShutterCallback, Camera.PictureCallback, Camera.PictureCallback)` in this mode but the subject may not be in focus. Auto focus starts when the parameter is set. Applications should not call `autoFocus(AutoFocusCallback)` in this mode. To stop continuous focus, applications should change the focus mode to other modes. Constant Value: `"continuous-video"`