# Android Camera autofocus when user holds camera still

Tags: java, android, camera, autofocus

I'm sure most of you have used an android phone before and taken a picture. Whenever the user changes the mobile phone's position and holds it steady, the camera focusses automatically. I'm having a hard time replicating this in my app. The autofocus() method is being called only once when the application is being launched. I have been searching for a solution these past 3 days and while reading the google documentation I stumbled upon the sensor method calls (such as when the user tilts the mobile forwards or backwards). I could use this API to achieve what I need but it sounds too dirty and too complicated. I'm sure there's another way around it.

All examples on the internet which I have found only focus when the user presses the screen or a button. I have also gone through several questions on SO to hopefully find what I am looking for but I was unsuccessful. I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7156403/is-there-an-efficient-way-to-do-continuous-auto-focus) question and that String is not compatible with my phone. For some reason the only focussing modes which I can use is fixed and auto.

I was hoping someone here would shed some light on the subject because I am at a loss.

Thankyou very much for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `camera.autoFocus(callback)` is a one-time function. You will need to call it in a loop to have it autofocus continuously. Preferably you would have a [motion detection via accelerometer or compass](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html) to detect when camera is moved.

Answer (score 3):

Since API 14 you can set this parameter

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE