# android camera continuous focus (on demand)

Tags: android, camera, autofocus

i am using samsung galaxy s2,i ve noticed that in video recording mode when i press record button the camera continuously focus on the object.but in preview mode it does n't.i want to use continuous auto focus in my application.it doesn't support this type of parameter.
[question on auto focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7156403/is-there-an-efficient-way-to-do-continuous-auto-focus)

the auto focus call back hold focus for some amount of time and after that it looses. 
and again most of the proposed solutions are not reliable.[proposed solutions.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5878042/android-camera-autofocus-on-demand)

can u suggest me a perfect solution which will act as inbuilt camera application.(in video recording.)
thank you!have a nice day!!

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the continuous autofocus mode `FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO` (starting from API level 9)? In this mode, focus is automatically adjusted permanently (it worked well for me)

See the documentation at http://developer.android.com:

- [Camera.Parameters#FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO)
- [Camera.Parameters.html#setFocusMode(java.lang.String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setFocusMode%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: On my samsung note3(KitKat) FOCUS_MODE_CONTINOUS_VIDEO seems to work better than FOCUS_MODE_CONTINOUS_PICTURE.